# How to express a vector which is retrieved from a matrix

Tags: notation

How to express a vector which is retrieved from a matrix. In other words, suppose I have a matrix $\mathbf{B},$ y is a the first column vector of the matrix. I am looking for the notation which is involved the matrix.

Comment: $Be_1$ is the first column of $B$, where $e_1$ is the first vector of the standard base.

Comment: What is wrong with using a few extra words to make it perfectly clear what it is you are trying to say?  I think its better to use words rather than uncommon notation that may instead confuse your reader.  Just say what you said here... $y$ is the first column vector of the matrix $B$.  No fancy notation needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following index notation:

y = B(: , 1)

Comment: That's just for MATLAB (and maybe another language).

Comment: Well, but since OP is looking for notations I think it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

As *Itay4* said on the comments, you can use the [standard basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis) vectors.

$e_1 = \{1,0,0,...,0\}^T$

$e_2 = \{0,1,0,...,0\}^T$

and so on...

The $i_{th}$ row of $B$ is: $r_i = e_i^T\,B$

The $i_{th}$ column of $B$ is: $c_i = B\,e_i$

A general term $(i,j)$ is: $B_{ij} = e_i^T\,B\,e_j$